# What kind of databases do desktop applications use?

Tags: database

I'm interested in knowing what type of databases are used by dekstop applications?

Are they normally embedded databases or just plaintext and xml files?

I cant see any database server requirements for the programs which I install? So how can they save their data?

Comment: Very vague question. Depends on the application a lot of the time. If they need a database embeded usually SQLite is used.

Comment: Word, excel, drivers, driver interfaces what do they use?

Comment: Why would Word and Excel need a database?

Comment: I dont know maybe recall the settings previously saved or text in the files

Comment: That is not what databases are used for. Individual `.xls` or `.docx` files used by Word/Excel are essentially compressed archives of several files that define the content. Settings can be stored in a `config.xml` (or `app.config`/`user.config`) file.

Comment: so there must be a config file of each excel or word files?

Comment: What? Why must there be? You're talking about individual files now instead of the application as a whole. A document of course contains as much information as it needs to within its file format, this is completely custom per document type, usually.

Comment: Where are the config files of whole application? In program files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No two programs are exactly the same, and it is entirely dependant on the storage requirements of the application.

If it needs a full RDBMS, applications tend to use embedded database platforms such as SQL Server Compact or SQLite. These are both components that are embedded into the application itself, and do not require an external server to be running to provide common database functionality such as SQL Querying.

On the flip side, if the data is lightweight or mostly textual, you could simply use a flat file storage system as mentioned such as XML.

Note that for some of my applications where performance is required, I've opted to use SQL Server LocalDB, which is an installable dependency but allows user-instances of databases to be loaded up on the fly, rather than a full installation of SQL Server Express that runs as a service and hosts databases permanently.